# Как запретить доступ к файлам и подкаталогам в каталоге assets с помощью .htaccess, чтобы при этом подключались и отображались css стили?

Tags: javascript, html, css, .htaccess, apache2.4

Нужно с помощью файла .htaccess запретить доступ пользователю к каталогу assets. Но чтобы при этом возможно было подключение css стилей, находящихся в каталоге assets/css, к .html файлу. (Apache2.4)

Пытался помещать файл .htaccess в каталог assets и писать там

```
Require all denied
```

при попытке открыть файл .htaccess сервер выкидывал 403, но при этом пропадали css стили из .html файла, оставалась лишь html вёрстка.

Пробовал писать в .htaccess

```
Options -Indexes
```

результат - доступ к каталогу assets и вложенным в него запрещался, css стили не пропадали (всё как нужно), но, например, я всё же мог просматривать файл assets/css/main.css

Comment: *при попытке прочитать или получить этот файл из браузера, выкидывалась 403* - импосибле

Comment: Надёжно никак. Достаточно просто и обычно достаточно хорошо — проверять referer.